# Difference in primary-key column order in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

We have one ycql table items where we have defined primary key on two columns.
Wanted to understand if there is any significance on the sequence of columns.

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    item_value text,
    list_id uuid,
    created_at timestamp,
    metadata jsonb,
    PRIMARY KEY ((item_value, listId))
) WITH default_time_to_live = 0
    AND transactions = {'enabled': 'true'};
```

For the above table, does it change the performance or partitioning logic if we change the sequence to below one.

```
PRIMARY KEY ((list_id, item_value))
```

Cardinality:

```
list_id-> (100)
item_value-> (10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

> For the above table, does it change the performance or partitioning logic if we change the sequence to below one.
> `PRIMARY KEY ((listId, item_value))`

No, it doesn't. Because both keys will be taken together as a single value and hashed.
You might have a little better on-disk compression when `list_id` is first because there will be less cardinality.
It would make a difference if your primary key was: `PRIMARY KEY ((listId), item_value)`
Which would hash only on the first column.